# How to give Bitcoin wallets as a gift

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I want to give Bitcoin as a gift to someone that has as little experience with them as I do.

Most importantly, I want to create a wallet (preferably offline, so I can just handover a USB stick with numbers stored on it, but online is also okay if it's with a trusted site) for them without involving their passport picture, email address etc.

I am happy to provide documents/setup 2FA myself as long as that data is not connected to the final wallet

I'm not talking about amounts that would raise any governments suspicion or reporting limits.

I prefer Bitcoin, but if the fact that I'd only purchase fractional coins makes things more difficult, I'm happy with liquid alternatives.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for something like [Open Dime](https://opendime.com/) -- much more secure than a USB stick, but no backups possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new bitcoin wallet offline with a website like this one
   https://walletgenerator.net/
2. Transfer the amount you want to give to your friend to this new
   wallet
3. Write the private key on a paper and give it to him then explain  that since you have created his wallet he is not the real owner and tell him to do step 1 and 2 by himself if he want to really own his coins